# Liferay -> Automatically deactivate new users at signup

Tags: liferay

Is it possible to deactivate users by default in liferay when they sign up so that the administrator could approve/activate their accounts later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [ModelListener](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-ModelListeners) for the User class - e.g. when a user is created first, your Listener should immediately set it to 'deactivated'.

You do this easiest in a custom hook that you'd have to write (see the linked wiki article). Hooks are quite easy to create with Liferay's plugin-sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ModelListener hook do this...

UserLocalServiceUtil.updateActive(userId, false);

Its really easy to write Hooks checkout Liferay documentation.